# The method showDialog(999) is undefined

Tags: android

I get the following errors in this code.

```
The method showDialog(int) is undefined for the type training details.
The constructor DatePickerDialog() is undefined.
The method getMenuInflator() is undefined.
```

How do I solve these errors? Please guide.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.empover.odch.R;

public class TrainingDetails extends BaseFragment
{
View view;

private EditText nameEdt;
private Spinner trainingTypes;
private Spinner trainerProfile;
private EditText descriptionEdt;

private Calendar calendar;
private EditText startDt;
private EditText endDt;
private int year, month, day;

String data1[] = {"1", "2", "3"};
String data2[] = {"a", "b", "c"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.training_details, container,false);

    nameEdt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name_edt);

    trainingTypes = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingtypes_spn);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data1);

    adapter_state1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    trainingTypes.setAdapter(adapter_state1);

    trainingTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String selTrainingTypes = data1[index];
            //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Selected: " + selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {

        }
    });

    trainerProfile = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.trainerprofile_spn);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data2);

    adapter_state2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    trainingTypes.setAdapter(adapter_state2);

    trainingTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String selTrainerProfiles = data2[index];
            //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Selected: " + selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {

        }
    });

    descriptionEdt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.description_edt);

    startDt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.startdate_edt);
    endDt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.enddate_edt); 

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month+1, day);

    return view;
}
public void setDate(View view)
{
    showDialog(999);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    if (id == 999)
    {
         return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
   {
      int x = arg2;
      x = x+1;
      showDate(arg1, x, arg3);
   }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    startDt.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/").append(month).append("/").append(year));
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
}
}
```

Comment: First `showDialog()` is deprecated, take a look here to learn how to show a dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

use:

```
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

Instead of:

```
showDialog(999);
```

use:

```
getActivity().showDialog(999);
```

Instead of:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
```

use:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), myDateListener, year, month, day);
```